# How to get the account the SQL Server service runs as with C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, service, account

Ideally, I would like to pass a SQL Server instance name (for instance, `.\SQLEXPRESS`) and get the name (or a SID) of the account that particular instance is running as. Something like this:

```
var serviceAccount = SomeClass.GetServiceAccount(".\SQLEXPRESS");
```

Maybe this info is stored somewhere in system registry or other well-known location? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: ["Query to find out Service Account details"](http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/10/23/query-to-find-out-service-account-details/)

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2008, we can get the information from below query:

```
SELECT value_data
FROM   sys.dm_server_registry
WHERE  value_name = 'ObjectName'
AND     registry_key = 'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER'
```

We can also use below approach:

```
SELECT DSS.servicename,
       DSS.startup_type_desc,
       DSS.status_desc,
       DSS.last_startup_time,
       DSS.service_account,
       DSS.is_clustered,
       DSS.cluster_nodename,
       DSS.filename,
       DSS.startup_type,
       DSS.status,
       DSS.process_id
FROM   sys.dm_server_services AS DSS;
```